# R: Search through multiple columns if value is present keep that row

Tags: r

What I want to do if search through each second column and if, within a row, one column has a value greater then 0.95 then keep it. Basically ever row retained must have at least one column that is >0.95. 
Example df:

```
     Id VALUE_Sample1 DetectionScore_Sample1 VALUE_Sample2 DetectionScore_Sample2
1 10265        -0.251                 0.8874       -0.1850                 0.2120
2 10265         0.560                 0.9989        0.6610                 0.9456
3 12346         0.874                 1.0000        0.7545                 0.9900
```

So I want to go through the 'DecetionScore_' columns and look for any values greater the 0.95 so the above would return.

```
     Id VALUE_Sample1 DetectionScore_Sample1 VALUE_Sample2 DetectionScore_Sample2
1 10265         0.560                 0.9989        0.6610                 0.9456
2 12346         0.874                 1.0000        0.7545                 0.9900
```

The code I have attempt is

```
newdf<-df[df[,(seq(3,151,2)] >= 0.95,]  ## col 1 is IDs
```

Any ideas how I could approach this?

Comment: It seems that the provided code does not have any row to be deleted. Am I missing something or maybe the question isn't clear to someone else?

Comment: `rowSums` is probably quicker than `apply` type solutions - `dat[rowSums(dat[grepl("^DetectionScore_",names(dat))]>0.95)>0,]`

Comment: @SabDeM My approach was rather then delete rows from the dataframe, I would create a new dataframe that will only take rows that meet the criteria. - Does that help?

Comment: @thelatemail I might not have been completely clear, or I'm not understanding your code. I want to look at each individual cell within the respective columns, if the cell is greater then 0.95 then retain then complete row.

Comment: @George - break it down and test it, it gives you exactly what you want. `dat[grepl("^DetectionScore_",names(dat))] > 0.95` is at the core of it, which will test each value. `rowSums` just counts if there is a hit in the row anywhere.

Comment: @George you are been clear now in the comment. Anyway the code provided by other users works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df[which(apply(df[,seq(3,151,2)], 1, max) > 0.95),]
```

Comment: Good idea. No need to wrap it with "which" though.